# How do I create an iOS UISlider that displays a UILabel that displays a value in a range 1 to 10?

Tags: iphone, ios, uislider

I am new to iOS development and having a hard time with the `UISlider`. I have added a `UISlider` to my `.xib` connected to the `.h` file and can see the action method in the `.m` file but when I try to set the minimum and maximum value in the `.xib` file in the UISlider attributes, XCode crashes. I think it has something to do with creating a value in the `- (IBAction)slider:(id)sender` method in the `.m` file but I am doing something wrong because everything I try causes XCode to crash.

Answer (score 7):

```
CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 200.0, 10.0);

// sliderAction will respond to the updated slider value
UISlider *slider = [[UISlider alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
[slider addTarget:self action:@selector(sliderAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

***// Set minimum and maximum value of Slider***

```
    slider.minimumValue = 0.0;
    slider.maximumValue = 10.0;
    slider.continuous = YES;

    // Initial value
    slider.value = 25.0;
```

**// Add slider to view**

```
    [self.view addSubview:slider];


- (IBAction)sliderAction:(id)sender{
    UISlider *MYslider = (UISlider *)sender;
    int SliderValue = (int)roundf(MYslider.value);
    uilable *sliderLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", SliderValue];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this code...

```
@interface SliderDemoViewController : UIViewController {

      UILabel *sliderLabel;
}

@end
```

Put the following code in the “SliderDemoViewController.m” file.

```
@implementation SliderDemoViewController

@synthesize sliderLabel;

- (void)dealloc {
  [sliderLabel release];
  [super dealloc];

}

-(IBAction) sliderChanged:(id) sender{

  UISlider *slider = (UISlider *) sender;

  int progressAsInt =(int)(slider.value + 0.5f);

  NSString *newText =[[NSString alloc]
                  initWithFormat:@"%d",progressAsInt];

  self.sliderLabel.text = newText;
  [newText release];
}


@end
```

and also see more Info about UISlider from this bellow link..

http://www.xprogress.com/post-35-uislider-tutorial-example-how-to-use-slider-in-iphone-sdk-xcode/

i hope this help you..

:)

Answer (score 1):

make sure your slider is connected to the action method..and assuming that the label has an outlet by the name sliderLabel..the action method for the slider to call as it’s value is changed can be implemented as:

```
- (IBAction)slider:(id)sender{
    UISlider *slider = (UISlider *)sender;
    int progressAsInt = (int)roundf(slider.value);
    sliderLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", progressAsInt];
}
```

here the value is rounded off to show integer values only..I am assuming that the sider isnt being implemented for a very small range like 0-1 but a larger range..and you have mentioned that you implemented slider in nib..minimum and maximum values can be set in the attribute inspector for the slider..if you do it programatically, it will be slightly different..

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 4 :**

**Initialization :**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let slider = UISlider()
    slider.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 250, height: 35)
    slider.center = self.view.center

    slider.minimumTrackTintColor = .green
    slider.maximumTrackTintColor = .red
    slider.thumbTintColor = .black

    slider.maximumValue = 100
    slider.minimumValue = 0
    slider.setValue(50, animated: false)

    slider.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.changeVlaue(_:)), for: .valueChanged)

    self.view.addSubview(slider)

}
```

**Handler**

```
@objc func changeVlaue(_ sender: UISlider) {
    print("value is" , Int(sender.value));
}
```